# Conditions for the Hamiltonian's spectrum to be discrete

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, mathematics

I came across [this article](http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/158.pdf) [1], in which the author studies some Hamiltonian that have a discrete spectrum even though they do not go to infinity at infinity.

In there, the author makes several claims, that I don't really get :

> If $H_1 \geqslant H_2$ and $H_2$ has a discrete spectrum, then so does $H_1$.

> If $\operatorname{Tr}e^{-tH}< \infty$ for any $t$, then $H$ has a discrete spectrum.

I would like to understand the intuition behind those results, as well as their formal proofs.

[1] *Some quantum operators with discrete spectrum but classically continuous spectrum*; B. Simon (Caltech); Published in: Annals Phys. 146 (1983), 209-220

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: The paper considers : \begin{align} H_{1}=-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}+x^{2} y^{2} \\ H_{2}=-\Delta_{D}^{Q} \quad \text { with zero boundary conditions on }\{(x, y)|| x y \mid \leqslant 1\} The author then claims that "since $H_2 \geqslant H_1 - 1$, any proof that $H_{1}$ has discrete spectrum will automatically imply that $H_{2}$ has discrete spectrum.

Comment: Without details on domains (and I find incredible that a paper by B. Simon was written in a that, say, “ sloppy “way), the first statement is too ambiguous. The latter is trivial if H is selfadjoint: as the trace exists the exponential is trace class, hence compact, so that its spectrum is discrete (up to the zero eigenvalue if any). The spectrum of the exponent is the logarithm of that spectrum and thus it is discrete as well.

Comment: https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiOwYTar7PwAhWNu6QKHfBvCjgQFjADegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEssential_spectrum&usg=AOvVaw3BEfpvUuoCdqfGuzqxQYEY

Comment: @ValterMoretti Wow, thank you! I never noticed that nuance before. I knew the definition of spectrum and wrongly assumed that the adjective "discrete" was applied to that set of numbers, rather than modifying the original definition. Gives me more sympathy for students who get misled by other familiar looking words... Words are an awful way to communicate. :)  I deleted my earlier comments so they don't lead anyone else astray.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly Do not worry: even in mathematical physics *discrete spectrum* is used with different meanings in very close areas. In the mathematical theory of quantum measurement has a different meaning. When one says that only observables with *discrete spectrum* have reproducible outcomes, the meaning is even more intricate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I propose a second answer because the first was affected by a trivial but devastating   mistake).

First of all

**Definition**. *A selfadjoint operator $A: D(A) \to H$, where $H$ is a complex Hilbert space and $D(A)\subset H$  a dense subspace,   has **discrete spectrum** if its spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is made of isolated points, thus eigenvalues, and the associated eigenspaces are all finite dimensional.*

A first fact is true.

**Proposition**. *Let $H$ be infinite dimensional and let $A =A^*$ be bounded below.*

*(a) If $A$  has discrete spectrum then the resolvent operator $(A -\lambda I)^{-1} : H \to D(A)$ is compact for every real  $\lambda\not \in \sigma(A)$.*

*(b) if the resolvent operator is compact for some real  $\lambda\not \in \sigma(A)$ then $A$ has discrete spectrum (and thus the resolvent is compact for all reals as above for (a)).*

**Remark**. The resolvent operators of selfadjoint operators are always defined in the whole Hilbert space when the parameter is not part of the spectrum. This is the case for closed operators as the selfadjoint ones. Furthermore, essentially by definition, $D(A-aI) =D(A)$.

**Proof**.(a) As the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional and $A$ must admit a Hilbert basis of eigenvectors, and finally every eigenspace is finite dimensional, the spectrum must contain infinite isolated points. Since the spectrum is closed, it contains its accumulation points. As the points of the spectrum are isolated, the spectrum cannot admit accumulation points at all, and thus it must be unbounded. Finally, we assumed that the spectrum is bounded below, so that  the only possibility is that it is made of a sequence of elements $$\lambda_1< \lambda_2 < ...< \lambda_n \to +\infty$$
From spectral calculus, if the real  $\lambda$ does not belong to the spectrum,
$$(A-\lambda I)^{-1}= \sum_n (\lambda_n-\lambda)^{-1}P_n$$
where $P_n$ is the orthogonal projector onto the finite dimensional eigenspace of $\lambda_n$.
The series converges in the uniform operator topology because
$$||\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}(\lambda_n-\lambda)^{-1}P_nx||^2\leq \sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}(\lambda_{n}-\lambda)^{-2}||P_nx||^2\leq (\lambda_{N}-\lambda)^{-2}||x||^2$$
and thus, taking the sup over the norm one vectors,
$$||\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}(\lambda_n-\lambda)^{-1}P_n||^2\leq (\lambda_{N}-\lambda)^{-2}\to 0.$$
We have established that the resolvent is the uniform limit of finite rank operators hence it is compact.

(b) immediately arises from the Hilbert-Schmidt decomposition theorem of selfadjoint compact operators and standard spectral calculus. QED

Now, and this is the best I managed to prove, we have my version of the obscure statement in Simon's paper.

**Theorem**. *Let  $A$ and $B$ be selfadjoint operators in the infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space $H$ such that*

*1. $D(B)\subset D(A)$,*

*2. $B \geq A$,* $\quad$ *(i.e. $\langle x, Bx\rangle \geq \langle x,Ax\rangle$ if $x\in D(B)$)*

*3. $A$ is bounded below.*

*Then $B$ has discrete spectrum if $A$ has discrete spectrum.*

**Proof**. Since $A\geq cI$ for some $c>-\infty$, (2) entails that $B\geq cI$ and furthermore $c$ is also a lower bound of both spectra, so that  $\lambda < c$ cannot belong to $\sigma(A)\cup \sigma(B)$. In view of (a) in the proposition above, to conclude it is sufficient to show that if $$X^{-1}:=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$$ is compact (with $\lambda$ as above), then $$Y^{-1}:=(B-\lambda I)^{-1}$$ is compact as well. To this end, observe that
$$Y^{-1} = X^{-1} (X Y^{-1})\:.$$
Since $D(X)=D(A)$, $D(Y)=D(B)$ and (1) holds, the compositions are well posed. In particular $Ran(Y^{-1}) = D(Y)\subset D(X)$. Now observe that, since $X$ is closed it being selfadjoint, and $Y^{-1}$ is bounded, the *closed graph theorem* easily implies that $X Y^{-1}: H \to H$ is bounded as well. Since $X^{-1}$ is compact,
$Y^{-1} = X^{-1} (X Y^{-1})$ is compact because it is the product of a bounded operator and a compact operator. QED